# Asus Transformer : no more sound after update to Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, audio, asus-eee-pad-transformer, ota-update

I updated my Asus Transformer TF101 to Android 4.0.3 last weekend and I have no sound anymore. Is this a known issue? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looks like you aren't the only one with this problem.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1523358&page=2) A simple reboot seems to be working for most people, with some having to do a factory reset. If you have to do that, don't forget to use an app such as Titanium Backup to back up your apps first.

Comment: True. I already rebooted it, and hadn't noticed the sound was ok, now. Thank you.